# Force close when opening gallary in Emulator

Tags: android, image

I'm trying to open my gallary and select one image there in my sdcard but it giving me an error for force close when i click a button to open a gallary, here my code

```
 public void openGallery(int req_code){

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select file to upload "), req_code);
   }
```

here my error
Force close..The Application Camera

[image]

**LOG Cat**

```
06-22 15:03:27.511: D/dalvikvm(179): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 6% free 6439K/6791K, paused 6ms+6ms
06-22 15:03:28.893: I/Process(13882): Sending signal. PID: 13882 SIG: 9
06-22 15:03:29.041: W/InputManagerService(80): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@414c1a38
06-22 15:03:30.121: I/ActivityManager(80): Process com.android.gallery (pid 13882) has died.
06-22 15:03:30.121: W/WindowManager(80): Failure taking screenshot for (230x143) to layer 21015
06-22 15:03:30.765: I/ActivityManager(80): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=content://media/external/images/media cmp=com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.ImageGallery } from pid 13692
06-22 15:03:30.771: W/WindowManager(80): Failure taking screenshot for (230x143) to layer 21015
06-22 15:03:30.878: I/ActivityManager(80): Start proc com.android.gallery for activity com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.ImageGallery: pid=13920 uid=10017 gids={1015, 1024, 1006, 2001, 3003}
06-22 15:03:32.221: W/ActivityManager(80): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{40e28e70 com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.ImageGallery}
06-22 15:03:33.151: D/AndroidRuntime(13920): Shutting down VM
06-22 15:03:33.151: W/dalvikvm(13920): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
06-22 15:03:33.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13920): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-22 15:03:33.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13920): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.ImageGallery}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
06-22 15:03:33.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13920):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1748)
06-22 15:03:33.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13920):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
06-22 15:03:33.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13920):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
06-22 15:03:33.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13920):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
06-22 15:03:33.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13920):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-22 15:03:33.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13920):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
06-22 15:03:33.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13920):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
06-22 15:03:33.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13920):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-22 15:03:33.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13920):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
06-22 15:03:33.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13920):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
06-22 15:03:33.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13920):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
06-22 15:03:33.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13920):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-22 15:03:33.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13920): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
06-22 15:03:33.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13920):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:204)
06-22 15:03:33.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13920):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2339)
06-22 15:03:33.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13920):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2546)
06-22 15:03:33.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13920):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:219)
06-22 15:03:33.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13920):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1780)
06-22 15:03:33.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13920):    at com.android.camera.ImageGallery.onCreate(ImageGallery.java:113)
06-22 15:03:33.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13920):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
06-22 15:03:33.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13920):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1712)
06-22 15:03:33.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13920):    ... 11 more
06-22 15:03:33.311: W/ActivityManager(80):   Force finishing activity com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.ImageGallery
06-22 15:03:33.401: W/WindowManager(80): Failure taking screenshot for (230x143) to layer 21020
```

Comment: The above code is perfect!! post your Entire code and Logcat

Comment: the error is APPLICATION CAMERA

Comment: which version of android you are using?

Comment: you need to post the LOGCAT OUTPUT. not a screenshot of your ErrorDialog. are you using a real device or emulator?

Comment: I'm using emulator, and the screenshot is my error

Comment: this is not the error. this is the ErrorDialog. how old are you? 10? the error is displayed in Eclipse->LogCat. and you get this error because you are using the Emulator, you should use a real device.

Comment: so how can I open it using emulator

Comment: you need to use a real device. the emulator does not have a camera.. maybe only if you attach a webcam. also emulators have a lot of bugs and are unstable. good luck.

Comment: @user1469168 Hey, sorry was on a break, totally forgot this thread. however it says why the problem occurs `06-22 15:03:33.241: E/AndroidRuntime(13920): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features`  it is probably somewhere here `at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1780) (line 1780)` or `at com.android.camera.ImageGallery.onCreate(ImageGallery.java:113) (line 113)` Delete the custom title, and try again

Comment: @user1469168 Ok, I thought that already (was on vacation), but I saw you hadn't choose an answer yet, but I assume it is resolved? If it is, you can make your own answer and accept it, so you have an accepted answer. And it can help other people in the future with this problem.

Comment: No, i didnt get any answer so then i choose to change and use server side

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
     startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
           android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
 startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE);
```

Then in onActivityForResult, call intent.getData() to get the Uri of the Image. Then you need to get the Image from the ContentProvider.

Comment: could you please add onActivityForResult sample also

Answer (score 0):

Use This :

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE);
        }
    });
```

Then in onActivityResult()

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                //   Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant open my Gallary when I click button for intent

Comment: ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE and REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE..it giving me errors and where did u get it ?

Comment: Put it as int ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE = -1;
    final int REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE = 1;

Comment: Start proc com.android.gallery for activity com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.ImageGallery: pid=22694 uid=10017 gids={1015, 1024, 1006, 2001, 3003}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot this in your manifest?

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Comment: @user1469168 Could you post your whole logcat, in your original question? That will help us alot to track where to problem is